# Is there a way to determine the source page for a cross-domain image request?

Tags: asp.net, cross-domain

I'm working on a set of sites that use a lot of cross-domain immge requests (our own site), and am getting a lot of 404 errors in our logs, but can't identify any actual pages where the images aren't showing.  Does anyone know of any method that can be used to find out what page requests contains the bad image references?

It occurs to me I could write an HttpModule for use on the sites to scan all pages for image references, and do some logging that I can use to track down the offending pages, but I wanted to see if there was as easier method first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request should have an 'Origin' header that specifies the calling domain. This header is set by the browser and can't be spoofed. The 'Referer' header will give you the full url to the calling page. You could write these header values to your log.